# How to specify is getting copied now

Tags: grammaticality

I am trying to say: ***something getting copied and it is in progress now***. So which one to use?

> It is *being* copied

or

> It is *getting* copied

Which one to use professionally?

Comment: Go for *...getting...*

Comment: @MaulikV "It is getting copied" doesn't sound better than "It is being copied". I don't see any reason to emphasize the action with "getting".

Comment: @Rathony somehow, *'being'* always make me think that we ourselves are involved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are acceptable.

"It is being copied" sounds more formal and neutral. If you want to say that a document is being photocopied, I would use that version.

"It is getting copied" sounds a little more colloquial.

To me it also suggests either that the copying is a complex procedure (e.g. copying a diamond necklace to make a replica version) or that it is said defensively (e.g. "Why haven't you copied that report yet?" "It's *getting* copied. It'll be ready in ten minutes.").